# Comparing two different objects for being the same values

Tags: java, object, compare, equality

I have two objects of type MyObject. Their private fields have things like `Integer, int, Long, long, String`, etc -- no fancy sub-objects or anything to this effect.

I want to check to see if their fields are equal. I am not trying to check if they are the same object in memory (the same reference?), which they shouldn't be anyway since these two objects are from separate lists / created separately.

What is the correct way to check if all the fields of one object have the same values as all the other fields of the second object?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem you're facing is. Do you feel you have "too many" fields for overriding `.equals`?

Comment: Override the `boolean equals(Object o)` method.

Comment: @Zircon I just want to make sure overriding `.equals` is the correct thing to do here, as opposed to doing `object1 == object2` or `object1.equals(object2)` or implementing `Comparable` or `Comparator` or something. Too many options and I am unsure which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to override the method `equals(Object)` and let your `IDE` implements it for you.

Comment: My IDE doesn't seem to have a way to implement it for me? (Android Studio). I just wrote @Override on`public boolean equals(Object obj)`, checked if `obj` was an instance of `myObject`, typecasted it, and then returned a big and-chain of field comparisons. Is this all I have to do?

Comment: provide your class definition with your fields in your question and your java version, I will generate it for you

Comment: I do see a generate function in Android Studio actually but I don't know which Template to use(IntelliJ Default, Apache commons-lang, Apache commons-lang 3, Objects.equal and hashCode (Guava), java.util.Objects.equals and hashCode (java 7+)).

Comment: choose IntelliJ  for example

Comment: or if you use java 8, you can use java.util.Objects.equals and hashCode (java 7+)

Comment: I used the IntelliJ Default. So now if I want to check for value equality of two objects, I check if `obj1.equals(obj2)`?

Comment: @ArukaJ you do need to override `hashCode()` when overriding `equals()`. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)): *Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.*

Comment: Is it ever the case that the fields are the same but somehow the hashcode would be different?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the equal method in your class and compare if the values of the two class are same return true else false.
example:

```
obj1.equals(obj2);
```

in your class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(YourClass obj) {
    // compare the values of both objets.
    // return true on success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.equals() to compare

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `Object`'s `equals` method is the best choice for your situation. You can either ensure the equality of every field of the object, or you can just compare a field or combination of fields that you know will be unique.

If you're using collections such as `Map`s, you might consider overriding `hashcode` using these fields instead, and then compare hashcodes in the `equals` method.

For your reference:

- `equals` should always determine if two objects are "equal" in concept (which usually means they have the same fields).
- `==` compares memory location, and thus equality between primitive types
- `Comparable` interface is used to order an object "ahead" or "behind" another object; useful for sorting arrays and collections.
- `Comparator` interface is similar to `Comparable` but uses a "third-party" object to compare two other objects. This `Comparator` can be passed into collection-sorting methods if you don't want your objects to be `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

mDo as @Raj K suggested. For example, if you have:

```
public class MyObject {
   int i1;
   long l1;
   long i2;
   // and a bunch of c'tors and methods
}
```

then your equals() method would be something like

```
public Boolean equals( Object o ) {
   if ( o instanceof MyObject ) {
      MyObject m = (MyObject)o;
      return (i1==m.i1) && (l1==m.l1) && (l2==m.l2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If any of your fields are Objects, you have to be a bit more careful, since you also have to first check for null's before checking whether

```
this.something.equals(m.something)
```